# Is it feasible to execute app's global function in Xcode Debugger Console?

Tags: xcode

I have paused my iOS app and would like to execute a global function from within the Xcode Console Debugger. The function is defined in one of the app files that are included in the target. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes using `e` command on the proper stack: (I used `main` here)

[image: Demo]
<sub>Tested on Xcode 15</sub>

Comment: Why it works on the scope number 14 and not in the scope number 9 ?